# Angular 4+ : How to use icons from svg file

Tags: css, angular, svg

I have a **icon.svg** file which has collection of icons. I want to use them in my app , as we show material icons.

Any idea how to include the file in app and use them ?

I have tried solution from :

[Custom font import in Angular4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465888/custom-font-import-in-angular4)

[SVG icons from external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42870069/svg-icons-from-external-file)

[how to generate webfont from SVG icons in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963465/how-to-generate-webfont-from-svg-icons-in-angular)

But i am not able to show the icon.

Here is how i want to use the icons : 
`<span class="icon-home"></span>`
then it should show the home icon. I am also ready to use css as shown in some tutorial 
`.icon-home:before 
{
  content: "\e900";
}`

Can somebody please make me understand how it works?

Comment: You're supposed to use [glyphter](https://glyphter.com/) or similar to create the font, download and load it in your project. You can drag&drop, resize and reposition each `<svg>` and set the class of the icons.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu i have .ttf and .woff file too for icons. Can you explain me how do i include and use in my app.

Comment: You download and place them in your app. You only need to include the provided `css` in your app. It is very important to keep the relative structure between the CSS file and the font files provided. If in the CSS font files are loaded from `fonts/someFontFileName` but you move the CSS and execute it from another location, it will no longer find the font files => you either move those too or you change the URL accordingly. I can't help more without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

You just can put the sprite file of svgs in the assets folder and use it in your template components